# Get duplicate users from orders table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to find a way to detect the users who have duplicate accounts and ordered from a table I have on my database.  I've made some complex queries and haven't been to solve my problem.

First thought was to group by `ip` and `count(user_id)` but users can have more than one order so these wll be counted as well (eg if I use the above, the ip "192.168.1.1" will return 3 and not 2 which I want

My data is like

```
| order_id  |  user_id  |     ip      |
---------------------------------------
| 1001      |   2       | 192.168.1.1 |    
| 1002      |   5       | 192.168.1.1 |    
| 1003      |   2       | 192.168.1.1 |    
| 1004      |   12      |   18.15.0.1 |    
| 1005      |   9       |    10.0.0.1 |
```

Result needed
IP 192.168.1.1 cause it has 2 different user_id

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `GROUP BY ip,user_id`?

Comment: and keep the count(user_id)?

Comment: You want `count(order_id)`, but I'm pretty sure they will have the same value. `count(order_id)` just makes it more obvious what you are doing

Comment: define 'duplicate accounts'

Comment: Hmmm I want to have the IP 192.168.1.1 returned as it has 2 user_ids...
Duplicate account = "same IP different user_id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for IPs given to more than one user? Then group by IP and count distinct users.

```
select ip
from mytable
group by ip
having count(distinct user_id) > 1;
```

EDIT: To get the users associated with that

```
select user_id, ip
from mytable
where ip in
(
  select ip
  from mytable
  group by ip
  having count(distinct user_id) > 1
);
```

And here is the same with an EXISTS clause:

```
select user_id, ip
from mytable
where exists
(
  select *
  from mytable other
  where other.ip = mytable.ip
  and other.user_id <> mytable.user_id
);
```

Comment: I am seeking to detect users who registered and ordered with diferent accounts but same IP address (duplicate users)

Comment: Okay, as we find the IPs, it is easy to get the user IDs for the IPs. I've added this to may answer.

Comment: You are close on what I am thinking... but members table with ip is refreshing every time they login so I try to get some more info using the user_id which wont change from table "orders"

Comment: Well, you have the user IDs, so it's just either a join to the users table (so you can show user data along with the IP) or another IN clause, right?

Comment: I have achieved that ... really thanks.. boosted me :)

Answer (score 2):

use `Distinct` inside your `Count`

```
SELECT COUNT(Distinct user_ID)
FROM table
GROUP BY ip
```

Comment: Ok, after the OP clarified, this is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.ip, t.user_id,
   (SELECT COUNT(1)
   FROM yourtable t3 WHERE t.user_id = t3.user_id
   AND t.ip = t3.ip) as total
FROM yourtable t
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'duplicate'
    FROM yourtable t2
    WHERE t.user_id = t2.user_id
    AND t.ip = t2.ip
    AND t.order_id < t2.order_id
)
```